# Cocoapods is installing old Pod version

Tags: ios, swift, terminal, cocoapods

I'm using `RxSwift` and other Rx-pods in my app, according to my `Podfile.lock` I use `RxSwift (3.2.0)`, but now I want to update the Pods to the latest versions.

So I remove the 4 Rx..-pods that I use from my `Podfile`, and run `pod install`, this removed the pods from the project and the `Podfile.lock`. The I re-add the 4 Rx..-pods and run `pod instal`again. This installs `RxSwift 2.6.1`... **Why?** - I'm expecting it to install the newest stable version of `RxSwift`, something like 3.6.1..

I tried removing everything listed by: `gem list --local | grep cocoapods` and reinstalling cocoapods by running: `gem install cocoapods`

I also tried running `pod repo update` without success.

I also tried just running `pod update`, without uninstalling the Pods first, also same outcome.

I suspect this to be an issue with my `cocoapods`-gem, not The Rx-pods..

**Edit** added `Podfile`:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'BrightFutures'
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'MBProgressHUD'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'Analytics', '~> 3.0'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
    pod 'Eureka', '~> 2.0.0-beta.1'
    pod 'RxCocoa'
    pod 'RxSwift'
    pod 'INTULocationManager'
    pod 'ReachabilitySwift', '~> 3'
    pod 'RxSwiftExt'
    pod 'RxMKMapView'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
        end
    end
end
```

**Edit** Added `pod outdated`dump:

```
Analyzing dependencies
The following pod updates are available:
- Alamofire 4.3.0 -> 4.5.0 (latest version 4.5.0)
- Analytics 3.5.7 -> 3.6.4 (latest version 3.6.4)
- BrightFutures 5.1.0 -> 5.2.0 (latest version 6.0.0-beta.1)
- Crashlytics 3.8.3 -> 3.8.5 (latest version 3.8.5)
- Eureka 2.0.0-beta.1 -> 2.0.1 (latest version 3.1.0)
- Fabric 1.6.11 -> 1.6.12 (latest version 1.6.12)
- Result 3.1.0 -> 3.2.3 (latest version 3.2.3)
- RxCocoa 3.2.0 -> 3.6.1 (latest version 3.6.1)
- RxSwift 3.2.0 -> 3.6.1 (latest version 3.6.1)
```

Comment: How are you declaring the `RxSwift` pod?

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: Have you tried running `pod update RxSwift`?

Comment: Yes, same issue

Comment: What does 'pod outdated' display?

Comment: @Wiingaard try with with    `pod 'RxSwift', '~> 3.0'`  or `pod 'RxSwift', '~> 3.6.1'`

Comment: Remove  pod 'RxMKMapView' from ur podFile and pod deintegrate and delete Podfile.lock and pod install . RxMKMapView required RxSwift 2.x.x version

Comment: So it's not possible to use RxMKMapView with RxSwift 3.x.x?

Answer (score 8):

You could try the following:

## Clearing CocoaPods' cache:

- rm -rf "${HOME}/Library/Caches/CocoaPods"
- rm -rf "`pwd`/Pods/" (while in your project's dir)
- Finally `pod update`

If you are using 0.38.0.beta1, you can just use `pod cache clean`

---

## Regenerate everything:

- rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/CocoaPods
- rm -rf Pods; rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*
- pod deintegrate; pod setup; pod install

---

## Set the version

```
pod 'RxSwift', '~> 3.0' # last version is 3.6.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of `RxMKMapView` needs RxCocoa 2.x.x. Apparently they need to update the Podspec, to allow RxCocoa 3.x.x. They did this in a commit, but it was never uploaded to cocoapods (or however that works). So I solved the problem by getting the pod from that commit. Because the `pod RxCocoa`didn’t have a minimum version requirement, cocoapods would just get latest version of RxCocoa that satisfied `pod RxMKMapView`, which was an old version (2.x.x). This was why I though something was wrong with my Cocoapod install, turns out it’s important to declare minimum versions of the wanted pods.. This solved the problem:

```
pod ‘RxCocoa’, ‘~> 3’
pod ‘RxSwift’, ‘~> 3’
pod ‘RxMKMapView’, :git => ‘https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxMKMapView.git', :commit => ‘6b86c6a’
```

Comment: Thanks! Had same issue with RxSwiftUtilities that was downgrading RxSwift. Installed latest RxSwiftUtilities commit and it solved the problem.